boost::asio reading all data from an ssl stream (without using EOF and connection: close headers)
i am developing a program that needs to read all the data from a boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::beast::tcp_stream>, etc a http webpage.
I have tried reading until EOF which works however it relies on the server closing the connection which is terribly inefficient when sending heavy amounts of requests (which may be common for the context my program is designed to be used in), so ideally id like to find another method.
I attempted using content-length headers but it is not reliable due to it not being mandatory for servers to use, i am interested in using 'tcp frames' however i cannot figure how to use with boost
I also also tried Stream->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(*buff, 1448) boost::bind(blahblah)) and reading until i get a bytes_transferred that is below 1448 but such method does not seem to work.
Notes:
Using socket_base::bytes_readable only seems to work on for getting the size of the encrypted data.
reading until a second \r\n\r\n wont work due to handling a myriad of file types.
Many thanks. <3

You have to implement the HTTP protocol.
For that purpose you can use the Boost Beast library which implements that on top of Asio. It does implement the myriad of transport encodings that you speak of, including the support for HTTP/1.1 features like Connection: keepalive, chunked encoding and optional content-length.
Here's a simple example client:
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::map<url, std::vector<char> > downloads;

    for (url u : std::vector<url>(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
        std::cout << "Downloading " << u << std::endl;

        auto& [sock, buffer] = connect(u);

        // download from the url target using HTTP GET
        {
            http::request<http::empty_body> req{http::verb::get, u.encoded_resource().decode(), 11};
            req.set(http::field::host, u.host());
            req.set(http::field::connection, "keep-alive");
            req.chunked(true);
            req.prepare_payload();
            http::write(sock, req);
        }

        {
            http::response<http::vector_body<char> > res;
            http::read(sock, buffer, res);

            downloads[u] = std::move(res.body());
        }
    }

    for (auto& [url,digits] : downloads) {
        auto file = path(url.encoded_resource().decode()).filename();

        auto frag = std::min(10ul, digits.size());
        std::cout << file << ": " << digits.size() << " digits: " << std::string_view(digits.data(), frag)
                  << "..." << std::string_view(digits.data() + digits.size() - frag, frag) << std::endl;
    }   
}

This leaves the normal connection code (that you must already have) in the separate function connect.
When run with e.g. digits of PI from calculat.io:

Full Listing
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/url.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
namespace asio  = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
namespace ssl   = asio::ssl;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::url;
using std::filesystem::path;

namespace /*globals*/ {
    ssl::context     sslctx(ssl::context::sslv23_client);
    asio::io_context ctx(1);
    auto             ex = ctx.get_executor();
    // asio::system_executor ex; // use implicit thread pool

    using Stream = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;
    struct Connection {
        Stream             stream;
        beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    };
    std::map<std::string, Connection, std::less<>> connections;
} // namespace

Connection& connect(url u) {
    u.normalize();
    std::string host    = u.host();
    std::string service = u.has_port() ? u.port() : "";
    if (service.empty()) {
        if (u.scheme() == "http") service = "80";
        else if (u.scheme() == "https") service = "443";
        else service = "80";
    }

    std::string key = host + ":" + service;

    if (auto it = connections.find(key); it != connections.end()) {
        std::cout << "Reused connection to " << key << std::endl;
        return it->second;
    }

    std::cout << "New connection to " << key << std::endl;

    auto& [k, conn]   = *connections.emplace(key, Stream{ex, sslctx}).first;
    auto eps          = tcp::resolver(ex).resolve(host, service);
    if (not SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(conn.stream.native_handle(), host.c_str()))
        throw std::runtime_error("SSL_set_tlsext_host_name failed");

    tcp::endpoint ep = connect(conn.stream.lowest_layer(), eps);
    if (ep.port() != 443)
        std::cout << "Warning: Assuming SSL on non-standard port " << ep << std::endl;

    conn.stream.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_none);
    conn.stream.handshake(Stream::client);

    return conn;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::map<url, std::vector<char> > downloads;

    for (url u : std::vector<url>(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
        std::cout << "Downloading " << u << std::endl;

        auto& [sock, buffer] = connect(u);

        // download from the url target using HTTP GET
        {
            http::request<http::empty_body> req{http::verb::get, u.encoded_resource().decode(), 11};
            req.set(http::field::host, u.host());
            req.set(http::field::connection, "keep-alive");
            req.chunked(true);
            req.prepare_payload();
            http::write(sock, req);
        }

        {
            http::response<http::vector_body<char> > res;
            http::read(sock, buffer, res);

            downloads[u] = std::move(res.body());
        }
    }

    for (auto& [url,digits] : downloads) {
        auto file = path(url.encoded_resource().decode()).filename();

        auto frag = std::min(10ul, digits.size());
        std::cout << file << ": " << digits.size() << " digits: " << std::string_view(digits.data(), frag)
                  << "..." << std::string_view(digits.data() + digits.size() - frag, frag) << std::endl;
    }   
}


cheers but boost::beast does not support http/2 so it isnt viable, but yeah i probs will need to implement the http protocall ;-;

You want to implement HTTP/2 from scratch? That's seems like a fool's errand if you had to post this question. Feels like I wasted a lot of time too, because you didn't mention it.
